# Requirements for Database Programming in SharePoint Server 2010 Environment

Tags: database, vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

A staff member is telling me that creating a database and the interfaces to allow field technicians and users add/edit records is impossible without a special programming environment installed on the programmer's desktop machine. The field personnel would use SharePoint via their web browsers to interact with the data. Our organization has deployed SharePoint Server 2010, all users have browsers, desktops have Windows XP and MS Office.

I don't completely believe the staff member, but I've been wrong before. The assertion that this developer cannot create anything useable without an upgrade to Win7, installation of a special development environment, and the like doesn't sit well with me. I've done a fair amount of programming, and when a compiled or assembled product is the result, I too have used "environments" but SO much can be done these days with VBA and its ability to reach back to running SQL and SharePoint that I'm having trouble agreeing that a fairly simplistic set of forms, queries and reports can't be cobbled together to do the straightforward tracking that we want to do.

Since I'm a pointy-haired manager now (and no longer coding in any respectable sense - those were the days) I'm hoping someone can tell me if this person is indeed correct, or if I need to call "BS" on this one. I certainly haven't asked for anything on the bleeding edge of database development to be undertaken.

Comment: I believe this question is more into Server Fault http://serverfault.com/ or Super User http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your staff member is correct. You can only develop for SharePoint on a machine running SharePoint. You can install SharePoint on a Windows 7 machine, but not on a previous operating system.

Unless, of course, you want to develop on a server OS?

Besides, do you really want developers making changes to your Production SharePoint instances? Directly?

Did you plan to use any form of source control?

Also, you don't do "database development" in SharePoint, in general. It's usually better to create SharePoint lists and content types, and if you don't know what those are, then you need to learn before you make any decisions about SharePoint development.

See [Patterns & Practices: Developing Applications for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx).